# Firebase Deployment CLI

Tags: firebase

Can any share the steps to to deploy website for testing on firebase using CLI.

firebase login

firebase init

firebase projects:list

firebase use   Node-firebase
firebase use   blue-plan

firebase deploy --only hosting:rndexperts

firebase hosting:channel:deploy nisha-rnde --expires 7d

what it goes to different sites, How I can choose that particular site, I don't know.